Setting evil-set-initial-state/evil-emacs-state-modes for Cider repl to Emacs-mode
By default fresh buffers are placed into Normal mode by Emacs, with evil running. I'm trying to get the REPL for cider-jack-in to start in Emacs-mode on my system.
I looked at the buffer list, and its mode is REPL[clj], but running the following

;; Buffer
;  * *cider-repl .config:localhost:37963(clj)*     971 REPL[clj]        

(add-to-list 'evil-emacs-state-modes 'REPL[clj])

Does nothing when starting another buffer, presumably because of the [] characters. I'm running Emacs 29 and Doom, but I think this question is more general than the Doom framework I have installed.
Just for completeness I tried running (evil-set-initial-state) but that gave an error
(evil-set-initial-state 'REPL[clj] 'emacs)

; =>  Wrong number of arguments: evil-set-initial-state, 3


'REPL[clj] are two objects - REPL and [clj].

With help from people on libera/#clojure, there is a buffer-local symbol major-mode which contains the major mode of the current buffer. Using doom's SPC-h-v and major-mode, I was able to ascertain that the mode is cider-repl-mode and not REPL[clj] as shown in Emac's buffer list (aside: where on earth is that set, and why is it useful to not show the actual mode in that list?).
TL;DR: (evil-set-initial-state 'cider-repl-mode 'emacs) works.
